# bind event on parent applying to child also

Tags: jquery, events, bind

How to prevent parent link with bind click event. li have anchor tag with href="page.html" and li have sub list ul when li anchor tag click's it redirects to page.html and show the sub list ul. how to stop parent li achor tag click event from redirectng page.html only show the sub list and click event on sub list anchortags any tip..

My question was dynamic menus that generates when pages adds and generated as top navigation menus where the menus links cant be change it will have a landing page. To avoid from this scenario on top of click event with slide down menus with jquery :

```
<ul>
<li><a href="home.html"></a></li>
<li><a href="page1.html"></a></li>
<li><a href="page2.html"></a>
    <ul>
       <li><a href="sub-page1.html"></a></li>
<li><a href="sub-page2.html"></a></li>
<li><a href="sub-page3.html"></a></li>
<li><a href="sub-page4.html"></a></li>
</ul></li>
<li><a href="#"></a></li></ul>

jquery: 
if ($(window).width() < 900) {
$('ul.dynamic').hide();
$("li.dynamic-children a").bind({
    click: function (e) {
        $(this).next("ul.dynamic").toggle();
        e.stopPropagation();
    }
});} else {
$('ul.dynamic').hide();
$("li.dynamic-children").bind({
    mouseenter: function () {
        $(this).find("ul.dynamic").slideDown(300);
    },
    mouseleave: function () {
        $('ul.dynamic').hide();
    }
});}
```

onlick page2.html li item sublist of ul item should display with slide down but page link should not be work the e.preventdefault works but fails the click event on sub links.

Comment: Please change your question to something that makes sence.

Comment: `$('#parent a').on('click',function(e){e.preventDefault()});` ???

Comment: Question could be a little clearer

Answer (score 0):

The click event is also bound to the child, because the child is in the parent with an event. The reason that happends is because it bubbles up the DOM-tree, if some parent has an event, its triggered

As far as I can make sense of what you ask, add a class (or something) to the `li` with a submenu, and add `event.preventDefault()` in the click handler like this:

```
$('element').on('click', function(event){
    event.preventDefault();
    // expand menu here
});
```

Another (imo better) solution would be to add a button to expand the menu beneath it. Just add something like `[+]` after the anchor and bind something to unfold it to that.
That way you can keep using the anchor as a working link, and provide users easy access to the submenu